# Batch upload to google cloud using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload multiple files at once using the google cloud python api, and am having trouble with it. Below is my code:

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("path_to_json")
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
with client.batch():
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            blob = bucket.blob("my_blob")
            blob.upload_from_filename("path_to_file",content_type="image/jpeg")
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

However, this is telling me that there are no deferred requests to make. I have tried doing it without `client.batch()` and it works but is too slow. I was wondering if anyone has ever encountered this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3139), the back-end API doesn't support batching "media" operations